MsBuild CustomTask to increment the version number in all projects of a solution simultaneously
The goal is that all assemblies (NuGet-Package) get a unique version number with each build. So far I have used the following for this:
<PackageVersion>6.0.$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd.HHmmss"))</PackageVersion>

The problem here is: if I have several projects in a solution and make a build on the solution, each project has a different version number. The projects are built one after the other and therefore the timestamps differ slightly.
My idea is to build an MsBuild task that generates the version number and makes it available to each project consistently via a variable.
So I have created a NuGet package to be able to attach the CustomTask to each project:
VersionHelperTask.cs
public class VersionHelperTask : Task
    {
        [Output]
        public string VersionNumber { get; set; }

        public override bool Execute()
        {
            Log.LogMessageFromText("Start VersionHelperTask", MessageImportance.Normal);

            VersionNumber = "1.2.3";

            Log.LogMessageFromText("End VersionHelperTask", MessageImportance.Normal);

            return true;
        }
    }

.props
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CustomTasksFolder>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tasks\netstandard2.0</CustomTasksFolder>
    <CustomTasksAssembly>$(CustomTasksFolder)\$(MSBuildThisFileName).dll</CustomTasksAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="VersionHelperTask" AssemblyFile="$(CustomTasksAssembly)"/>
</Project>

.targets
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="VersionHelperTask" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild" >
    <Message Text="In PrepareForBuild" Importance="high"/>
    <!--Calling our custom task-->
    <VersionHelperTask>
      <Output TaskParameter="VersionNumber" PropertyName="VersionNumber" />
    </VersionHelperTask>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="InfoMessages" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="VersionNumber: $(VersionNumber)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
</Project>

And this is what my code looks like in the target project:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AssemblyVersion>$(VersionNumber)</AssemblyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="InfoMessages2" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="VersionNumber2: $(VersionNumber)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ALHBuildVersionHelper" Version="6.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>


My problem is: the variable does not seem to be filled, as the version number is always 1.0.0.
However, my log output says otherwise:
.....
VersionHelperTask:
  In PrepareForBuild
  Start VersionHelperTask
  End VersionHelperTask
....
1>Ziel "InfoMessages2":
1>    VersionNumber2: 1.2.3
1>Ziel "InfoMessages":
1>    VersionNumber: 1.2.3

Do you have any ideas?
